# C / Objective-C: Refactor array assginment

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I'm trying to avoid if/else statements to check for array.count.  What's the best way to accomplish this with minimal amount of Code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *_sectionMap;
NSMutableArray *sections;
NSMutableArray *sectionHeaderLabel;
```

sections.count & sectionsHeader.count will vary: minimum 1 Object; maximum 7 objects;

**Currently, I'm getting an error `index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'`
 if my arrays don't have all 7 objects.**

```
[_sectionMap setValue:@"_iceCreamSectionObjects" forKey:kCoffee];
[_sectionMap setValue:@"_lunchSectionObjects" forKey:kLunch];
[_sectionMap setValue:@"_dinnerSectionObjects" forKey:kDinner];
[_sectionMap setValue:@"_movieSectionObjects" forKey:kMovies];
[_sectionMap setValue:@"_activity1SectionObjects" forKey:kActivity1];
[_sectionMap setValue:@"_activity2SectionObjects" forKey:kActivity2];
[_sectionMap setValue:@"_activity3SectionObjects" forKey:kActivity3];

NSArray *sectionZero = _recipientSectionObjects;
NSArray *sectionOne = _meetUpSectionObjects;
NSArray *sectionTwo = [_sectionMap valueForKey:[sections objectAtIndex:0]];
NSArray *sectionThree = [_sectionMap valueForKey:[sections objectAtIndex:1]];
NSArray *sectionFour = [_sectionMap valueForKey:[sections objectAtIndex:2]];
NSArray *sectionFive = [_sectionMap valueForKey:[sections objectAtIndex:3]];
NSArray *sectionSix = [_sectionMap valueForKey:[sections objectAtIndex:4]];
NSArray *sectionSeven = [_sectionMap valueForKey:[sections objectAtIndex:5]];
NSArray *sectionEight = [_sectionMap valueForKey:[sections objectAtIndex:6]];

NSString *sectionZeroLabel = @"Recipient";
NSString *sectionOneLabel = @"Meetup";
NSString *sectionTwoLabel = [sectionHeaderLabel objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *sectionThreeLabel = [sectionHeaderLabel objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *sectionFourLabel = [sectionHeaderLabel objectAtIndex:2];
NSString *sectionFiveLabel = [sectionHeaderLabel objectAtIndex:3];
NSString *sectionSixLabel = [sectionHeaderLabel objectAtIndex:4];
NSString *sectionSevenLabel = [sectionHeaderLabel objectAtIndex:5];
NSString *sectionEightLabel = [sectionHeaderLabel objectAtIndex:6];
NSString *sectionNineLabel = @"Transportation There";
NSString *sectionTenLabel = @"Transportation Back";
```

Comment: Because 3 is larger than 2, it is considered out of bounds when the array has the bounding of [0..2]. As the error implies.

Comment: I get it.  But I need to refactor.  I'm trying to avoid bunch of if/else statements to check the array.count.

Comment: You are right there, about the refactoring. Start with that and when you able to actually read the code (no offense) I'm sure you will find the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing but I think you're looking for a *computed goto*, which is just what the `switch` statement happens to be. Assuming you're using ARC, so reference variables default to `nil`, the following code will set the variables based on the size of `sections` leaving excess ones as `nil`:

```
NSArray *sectionZero, *sectionOne, *sectionTwo, *sectionThree, *sectionFour, *sectionFive, *sectionSix, *sectionSeven, *sectionEight;

switch (sections.count)
{
   case 7:
      sectionEight = [_sectionMap valueForKey:[sections objectAtIndex:6]];
   case 6:
      sectionSeven = [_sectionMap valueForKey:[sections objectAtIndex:5]];
   case 5:
      sectionSix = [_sectionMap valueForKey:[sections objectAtIndex:4]];
   case 4:
      sectionFive = [_sectionMap valueForKey:[sections objectAtIndex:3]];
   case 3:
      sectionFour = [_sectionMap valueForKey:[sections objectAtIndex:2]];
   case 2:
      sectionThree = [_sectionMap valueForKey:[sections objectAtIndex:1]];
   case 1:
      sectionTwo = [_sectionMap valueForKey:[sections objectAtIndex:0]];
      sectionOne = _meetUpSectionObjects;
      sectionZero = _recipientSectionObjects;
      break;

   default:
      // handle error
}
```

Note the lack of `break` statements - each label just falls through to the next.

HTH.